# Logout User MSAL azure library in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure, adal, azure-ad-msal

I am facing issue for the logout for using MSAL library.

I had used the library from : https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc

I am trying to logout and then login again with different credential but it does not work.

The function for logout is :

[self.msalClient removeUser:self.user error:&error_];

Please help

Answer (score 2):

It will store the cache for the user who logged in. So you need to remove the cache as well like this.

```
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieJar = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
     for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [cookieJar cookies]) {
           if ([cookie.name isEqualToString:@"MSISAuth"] ||
               [cookie.name isEqualToString:@"MSISAuthenticated"] ||
               [cookie.name isEqualToString:@"MSISLoopDetectionCookie"]) {
                    [cookieJar deleteCookie:cookie];
                }
            }
   [self.msalClient removeUser:self.user error:&error_];
```

And there are some other options you can add while logging in like this

```
 [authContext acquireTokenWithResource:resource clientId:clientId redirectUri:[NSURL URLWithString:redirectURI] promptBehavior:AD_PROMPT_ALWAYS userId:nil extraQueryParameters:nil completionBlock:^(ADAuthenticationResult *result) {

  }];
```

Where `AD_PROMPT_ALWAYS` will ask user to enter username and password every time he logged in irrespective to cache.

`AD_PROMPT_REFRESH_SESSION` will open login screen but password will save. So if you touch on userId it will get required tokens.

`AD_PROMPT_AUTO` based on session expire time will redirect to login